# Algorithms - In which relation to the big O notation are the functions lg n and ln n?

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation

I want to prove in which relation the two functions stand to each other with the help of a proof. But how?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for $a,b>0$ we have $\log_an=(\log_ab)(\log_bn)$.